# script should run when the page is loaded for the second time

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, pageload

This code is to run a script once a week.

```
<?php
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30; 
setcookie("count", "yes", $expire);
if (isset($_COOKIE["count"]))
$fb="none()";
else
$fb="facebook()";
?>
```

I wish to load the same in such a way that, the script is ignored for the first time and runs on the second time. From there-on no script call for throughout the week.

Answer (score 0):

Try with unset the cookie before it sets like

```
unset($_COOKIE['count']); //or simple set cookie with numm time experies like setcookie('count','','0')
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30; 
setcookie("count", "yes", $expire);
if (isset($_COOKIE["count"]))
    $fb="none()";
else
    $fb="facebook()";
```